# android Read Logcat in Background 

Tags: android

I have made one application that read logcat perfectly but now i want to read logcat in background with the help of broadcast receiver. The problem is i am not able to find any action-intent for reading logcat. so if anyone have any idea regarding this ?

Comment: I don't think there is broadcast for log events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read logcat first of all you need persmission to be added in Manifest

```
<manifest ...>     
...     
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission> 
</manifest>
```

Also if you need to read Logs and all you can easily do with [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#User_Interaction)

Hope this will be helpful...

Happy coding